# Почему FragmentManager не дает сделать разную анимацию?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я пытаюсь заменить фрагмент в контейнере:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Однако на строке `fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);`
выскакивает ошибка:

> Must be one of: FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE,
>   FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE

Почему выскакивает эта ошибка, если так много видов анимации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно перед

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
```

добавить такую строку

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_fragment_in, R.anim.anim_fragment_out);
```